# Retrofit and RxJava, avoiding callback hell

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

So currently, Im making an async network request with a date parameter (using Retrofit), and if that request returns with a response code that isnt 200 (or if its 429, 400, or if the response body is just null, whatever is easiest to determine), I make a new request with a date parameter 1 day earlier. Again, if this request comes back with a response code that isnt 200, I make one more request with a date 1 day earlier than the previous, for a total of 3 possible requests if the first two fail.

I'm currently achieving this with a bunch of callbacks and calling a new method set up to perform the request with the day -1 for each try.

I know that I can achieve a cleaner solution with Rx and Retrofits built in Rx features. How would this be done?

Comment: What retrofit version?

Comment: @NikoYuwono 2.0.0-beta2

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add RxAndroid and RxJava adapter in your dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
```

and then you need to register the call adapter to your Retrofit declaration

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(myBaseurl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

And then you can change your service interface return type from Call to Observable

```
public interface MyAPIService {

    @POST("user")
    Call<User> getUser();

    @POST("user")
    Observable<Response<User>> getUserWithRxJava();

    @POST("user_friends")
    Observable<Response<List<User>>> getUserFriends();
}
```

And this is an example for chaining call

```
myService.getUserWithRxJava()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .flatMap(new Func1<Response<User>, Observable<Response<List<User>>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<Home>> call(Response<User> responseUser) {
            // You can also use responseUser.code to get the response code
            // but isSuccess() function will return true if the code 
            // is in the range [200..300)
            if (responseUser.isSuccess()) {
                return myService.getUserFriends();
            } else {
                // You can also use Observable.empty() if you want to ignore unsuccessful response
                return Observable.error(myThrowable);
            }
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<List<User>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            // TODO Completed
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // TODO Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Response<List<User>> friendListResponse) {
            // TODO do something with the data
            // To get the serialized data you can use friendListResponse.body();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The non-200 responses should come back as `RetrofitError` objects, which contain `Response` objects with a status code.

You could do something like this:

```
observable
    .retryWhen(new RetryStrategy())
    .subscribe(...);
```

and `RetryStrategy` might look like this (note, I'm using retrolambda, so wherever you see `->` just replace with a new anonymous inner class):

```
public class RetryStrategy implements Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

    public RetryStrategy() {}

    @Override
    public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
        return attempts.flatMap((throwable) -> {
            if (throwable instanceof RetrofitError) {
                RetrofitError error = (RetrofitError) throwable;
                if (error.getKind() == RetrofitError.Kind.HTTP) {
                    if (error.getResponse().getStatus() == 401) {

                        // This is where you attempt to recover
                        return someRecoveryObservable???;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Bubble any other errors back up, e.g. connection loss.
            return Observable.error(throwable);
        });
    }
}
```

You could also implement [Exponential Backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) here by adding support for a retry count, along with using `Observable.timer(long, TimeUnit)` in your recovery phase (and compute the timing based on the current number of tries).  Spotty connection problems sometimes benefit greatly from this approach - especially with fire & forget tasks that run in the background.